# How to manage SSL and non-SSL Websphere MQ using resource adapter?

Tags: ssl, jms, ibm-mq

My application is talking to two Websphere MQ systems. One is SSL enabled, the other is not. I am using wmq.jmsra.rar, the resource adapter.

I am not able to write/read on both the systems. I am getting "MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE" if I set different values for sslFipsRequired property in resource adapter.

Is there a way I can manage this two systems simultaneously using resource adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the FIPS specification. To be FIPS compliant in Java the entire JVM must conform not just the connection you care about. It's for this reason that the non-SSL connection doesn't work.

Do you really require FIPS mode, or are you using it to work around another problem?

Comment: We are using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA as ssl encryption which is FIPS compliant. Now, in that case I need to make sslFipsRequired=true.

Comment: You don't need to enable FIPS mode to use a cipherspec which happens to be FIPS compliant. You only need to enable FIPS mode if your environment has a requirement to be FIPS compliant. It sounds like your solution is to turn off FIPS mode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did turn FIPS mode off and it worked.

Comment: Just one more question. Is this behaviour of FIPS mode requirement(limitation?) applicable only for IBM MQ or it behaves the same way in other queue environments as well e.g. ActiveMQ, Rabbit etc?

Comment: I'm not certain how others have interpreted FIPS, but I know that IBM have stated previously that this is how they've interpreted it. I would assume that all vendors who have been FIPS certified would be subject to this same requirement.